# Defining a function which returns functions in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to do the following simple thing: given a topological space, extract its topology and view it as a poset. For that, I imported Topology.thy and Orders.thy and tried something along these lines

`fun undtop :: "'a top ⇒'a partial_order" where
"undtop T =  (leq ::"T ⇒ T ⇒ bool" where
"leq x y = (x ⊆ y)")"`

where `'a top` is the type `'a set set` and `partial_order` is of type `'a=>'a => bool` (the theory Orders.thy defines a class class `partial_order`) . The idea was that some T of type `a' top` should give the topology and then `undtop` would pick such a T and associate a partial order `leq`, viewed as a map  `T => T => bool`. Clearly this is not how it works, so I'd like to ask

1) How would you define a function that picks each T of a certain type and defines a new function with domain T?

2) How to specify that this T of type `'a top` is a topology, and not just a random collection of subsets, i.e how do I tell Isabelle that it should obey the axioms of the locale "topology" in Topology.thy?

Thank you for the support, as a beginner I'm still struggling with the syntax and the way Isabelle operates.

Comment: 1) In Isabelle/HOL, types cannot be arguments to functions. You either have to formalize your ideas on a higher level (using locales or type classes) or at the object level using sets.

2) I'm not quite sure which theories you are referring to by `Topology.thy` and `Orders.thy`. The standard Isabelle/HOL session has a Theory `Topological_Spaces` http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Topological_Spaces.html, and I'd suggest using that one.